# VHDL multiplexer testbench error

Tags: vhdl

I am new to vhdl and trying to make testbench for multiplexer with 5 select lines but it gives me errors (the code is very long so I just copied the part which include the errors )

The code:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    entity Mux_4_to_1_tb is
    end Mux_4_to_1_tb;

    architecture tb of Mux_4_to_1_tb is

    component Mux_4_to_1 is
      port( clock : in std_logic;
        D0, D1, D2, D3 : in std_logic; -- the data lines D0=A0 D1=A1 D2=B0 D3=B1
            S0, S1, S2, S3, S4  : in std_logic; -- the selector switches
            F : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
        );-- the output
    end component;
    constant clockperiod : time := 20 ns;
    signal D0, D1, D2, D3, S0, S1 , S2, S3, S4  , F : std_logic;
    signal selectors : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

    begin
    mapping: Mux_4_to_1 port map(D0, D1, D2, D3, S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, F );

    --Concurrent processes
    process
    begin   

      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '1';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '1'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '1'; S4 <= '1';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '1'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '1'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '1';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '1'; S3 <= '1'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '1'; S3 <= '1'; S4 <= '1';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '1'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '1'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '1';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '1'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '1'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '1'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '1'; S4 <= '1';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '1'; S2 <= '1'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '1'; S2 <= '1'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '1';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '1'; S2 <= '1'; S3 <= '1'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '0'; S1 <= '1'; S2 <= '1'; S3 <= '1'; S4 <= '1';wait for clockperiod;
      S0 <= '1'; S1 <= '0'; S2 <= '0'; S3 <= '0'; S4 <= '0';wait for clockperiod;
      end process;

      process(S4, S3, S2, S1, S0)
      begin
       selectors <= S0&S1&S2&S3&S4;
        end process;

       process
       begin

      --The "assert" keyword allows you to test certain 
      --conditions. In other words, the point of assertion is
      --to allow you to inspect what you expect.

      --Two test cases are presented here. Feel free 
      --to add your own cases.

       --TEST 1
         D0 <= '0';
        D1 <= '1';
        D2 <= '0';
        D3 <= '1';
        wait for clockperiod;
        case selectors is
         when "00000" =>
           assert(F => "000") report "Error 1: 00000" severity error;
```

Error:

> ** Error: E:\OneDrive\Engineering\Digital Circuit Design\TestBench.vhd(70): (vcom-1581) No feasible entries for infix operator '='.
> ** Error: E:\OneDrive\Engineering\Digital Circuit Design\TestBench.vhd(70): Type error resolving infix expression "=" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.

The error point me to the line with the assert word.

Also i get this error at the end of the code

code:

```
 when others =>
     assert true;
  end case;
end process;
end tb;
```

Error:

> ** Error: E:\OneDrive\Engineering\Digital Circuit Design\TestBench.vhd(229): VHDL Compiler exiting

The error point me to the last line here.

Comment: Why do you have `assert true`? It's useless, it will never show. Maybe it is the reason for compiler error?

Comment: `assert(F => "000")` is an error, F is a std_logic object there is no `=>` operator to compare it to string `"000"` as a value of a compatible array type. Remove the superfluous parentheses and you may get a more meaningful error message. The fix appears to be relational testing (equality) against '0' noting the `F` output port std_logic_vector of the mux is inconsistent with it's std_logic input ports. Then again is it really a mux? You don't provide an [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The declaration of signal `F` may be in error.

Comment: There's a semantic error involving `F`. It's declared as a std_logic object and can't be compared to "000". Without seeing he code for `Mux_4_to_1` a reader can't tell what `F` is supposed to be, in it's component port declaration it is a std_logic_vector. Changing the signal `F` declaration to `signal F:   std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);`  shows a problem in the parameters for `mapping`, it's missing a `clock` formal association, missing outputs (`F`) aren't errors.  Use named association. Add a clock association.  Fix the assertion condition (e.g.`>=` not `=>` ).

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing any insight into how this testbench is supposed to operate without revealing the contents of `Mux_4_to_1`.

There are two things wrong with the assertion statement condition:

```
assert(F => "000")
```

`F` is declared as type std_logic which is not an array type and can't be compared to a string value (which would have an array type determinable by context). Also the relational operator should be `>=` and not `=>`, read as 'greater than or equal to'. `=>` is a delimiter used in association.

Changing the relational operator and changing the declaration for `F`:

```
signal D0, D1, D2, D3, S0, S1 , S2, S3, S4 :  std_logic; --  , F : std_logic;
signal F:   std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
```

generate an error telling us `F` can't be associated with `S4`, telling us you have a parameter list error.  You don't have enough parameters. It's not an error to not provide an association for outputs which is why it wasn't noticed before, although the reader might assume you changed the declaration of `F` to get rid of that error a priori.

Adding a signal declaration for a clock:

```
constant clockperiod : time := 20 ns;
signal clock:   std_logic;
```

and adding an association:

```
begin
-- mapping: Mux_4_to_1 port map(D0, D1, D2, D3, S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, F );
mapping: 
    Mux_4_to_1 
        port map (
            clock => clock,
            D0 => D0,
            D1 => D1,
            D2 => D2,
            D3 => D3, 
            S0 => S0,
            S1 => S1,
            S2 => S2,
            S3 => S3,
            S4 => S4, 
            F => F
        );
```

allows your code to analyze(by concatenating the code found with the others choice to the end of the VHDL code, you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

NOTES:

1. `clock` is not shown driven in the change description and if needed for your tests should be driven by the testbench.
2. Formal association is shown in the port map for the instantation of `Mux_4_to_1`, it allows you to see missing or wrong formal to actual port associations.
3. Superfluous parentheses surrounding conditions may obscure errors. They are only legal if the expression they contain is legal without them. It can change the error message you see. The lack of a proper relational operator results in a syntax error.